# Xcode 4 Build Settings Display Abnormal

Tags: ios, xcode, build-settings

**Normal** Display (Xcode 4.2 4D199, Mac OS X Lion):

[image: normal display]

**Abnormal Display** (Xcode 4.2 4C199, Mac OS X Snow Leopard):

[image: abnormal display]

It occurs in one day I woke up, I don't know why and how to solve it. and I have reinstall Xcode and restart system many times.

Comment: the lack of detail in this question is abnormal, too

Comment: -_- I'm editing and English is something hard to me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you may be looking for the "Show Values" / "Show Definitions" toggle in the "Editor" menu. Depending on the version of Xcode, the menu choice may be labeled "Show Raw Keys & Values", but still under the "Editor" menu.

Comment: you're right Jay (and I'm deleting my answer in the process). +1 to you.

Comment: Thanks all of you!   and +1 orally.  :-(